# Spring MVC and Hibernate - How to save data in two tables when persisting an object?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I want to accomplish the following:

A user can post a message, with a title and a description. He can also leave either his email address, his phone number, or both.

I want to store the info about his message in one table, with the columns id, userId, title and description.
I want to store the info about his contact info in another table, with the columns id, messageId, phoneNumber and email.
I want to be able to list the messages. For each message, I also want to print the phone number and the email address.

I want to store the contact info in a different table for different reasons, I am not able to store them with the message, in the message table.

I don't know what is the best way to accomplish this, especially knowing that I want to be able to retrieve a contact info with the ID of a Message.

I have tried multiple ways, with @OneToOne, @JoinColumn or @SecondaryTable but cannot get this to work.

Here is what I have right now:

Message class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="messages")
public class Message implements Serializable {
    private int idMessage;
    private int userId;
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private Contact contact;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="idMessage")
    public int getId() {
        return idMessage;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;    
    }

    @Column(name="userId", nullable=false)
    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }


    @Column(name="title", nullable=false)
    public int getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(int title) {
        this.title = title;
    }


    @Column(name="description", nullable=false)
    public int getDescription() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setDescription(int description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE})
    @JoinColumn(name="contactId", nullable=false)
    public Contact getContact() {
        return contact;
    }

    public void setContact(Contact contact) {
        this.contact = contact;
    }
}
```

Now, here is my contact class:
**Edit: I did add the attribute `messageId` in the Contact class. I also added the column in the Contact table and added a foreign key pointing to the id column of the Messages table.**
    @Entity
    @Table(name="contacts")
    public class Contact {

```
    private String id;
    private int messageId;
    private Message message;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String email;

    public Contact(Message message, String phoneNumber, String email) {
        this.message= message;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="ID")
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "contact")
    public Message getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(Message message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    @Column(name="phoneNumber", nullable=true)
    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    @Column(name="email", nullable=true)
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

}
```

Some of my JSP code, please note that I did put contact.email and contact.phoneNumber in the `path` attribute for email and phone number fields:

```
<form:form method="post" commandName="ad">
            <table width="95%" bgcolor="f8f8ff" border="0" cellspacing="0"
                cellpadding="5">

                <tr>
                    <td align="right" width="20%">Title *</td>
                    <td width="20%"><form:input size="64" path="title" class="input-xxlarge"/></td>
                    <td width="60%"><form:errors path="title" cssClass="error" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right" width="20%">Description *</td>
                    <td width="20%">
                        <%-- <form:input path="description" /> --%> <textarea rows="3"></textarea>
                    </td>
                    <td width="60%"><form:errors path="description"
                            cssClass="error" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right" width="20%">Phone Number *</td>
                    <td width="20%"><form:input path="contact.phoneNumber" /></td>
                    <td width="60%"><form:errors path="contact.phoneNumber" cssClass="error" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right" width="20%">Email *</td>
                    <td width="20%"><form:input path="contact.email" /></td>
                    <td width="60%"><form:errors path="contact.email" cssClass="error" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

Comment: Hi, which part it doesn't work? can not store in the database or can't show in the page. seems that you entities are good. It should be onetoone relationship.

Comment: When trying to load my list of Message, I got the following exception: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists: [com.domain.Contact#]

Comment: OK, you mean the data can be store in both tables of the DB? according to the error info, it seems the id that you use to get Contact, can not get result. you can check what the id is and does the data exist in the Contact table with this id.

Comment: Regarding the @JoinColumn annotation in the Message class, shouldn't it reference the name of the id column in the Contact table? Right now it is set to the following: @JoinColumn(name="messageId", nullable=false), which, as a result, creates a column called "messageId" in my table "Messages", but I already have a column in the "Messages" table called "id".

Comment: wow, definitely it's a problem. @JoinColumn means which column that you want to use to connect with another table, this case it should be id column.

Comment: How is it supposed to know to which table I want to join that column to? Right now I only have the OneToOne annotation as well as the JoinColumn. On the other side (The Contact class), I do have the OneToOne annotation with the mappedBy attribute set to "contact".

Comment: I can properly list my Messages now but when I am trying to insert a message I got the following: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'phone' of bean class [com.domain.Ad]: Bean property 'phone' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?

Comment: you Contact domain show be Serializable too.

Answer (score 1):

```
@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private Contact contact;
```

This means that:

- for each Message there is exactly one Contact (and one contact is used by only one message)
- whenever you perform a save, update or delete operation on a Message, that operation is cascaded to the contact table.

Comment: Yes, that it exactly what I want.

Comment: Right now, when trying to insert a message, I got the following error message: Invalid property 'phone' of bean class [com.domain.Ad]: Bean property 'phone' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?